# NodeJs : TypeError: require(…) is not a function

Tags: node.js, npm

Here are my code and error :

server.js

```
var app = require("express")();
var http = require('http').server(app);
var io = require("socket.io")(http);

//app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/static"));
app.get("/", function (req, res, next) {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + "/static/index.html");
})

http.listen(8000);
console.log("server run on port 8000");
```

Erorr

```
TypeError: require(...).server is not a function
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Maziar\Desktop\chat\server.js:2:28)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1063:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1092:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:928:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:769:14)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:72:12)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47
```

Please help me to fix the error .
Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is

```js
const http = require('http').createServer(app);
```

instead of

```js
const http = require('http').server(app);
```

The sample code provided by socket io in the [documentation](https://socket.io/get-started/chat/) is a good way to start:

```js
const app = require('express')();
const http = require('http').createServer(app);

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.send('<h1>Hello world</h1>');
});

http.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log('listening on *:3000');
});
```

As a side note, use `const` or `let` instead of `var`.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use the module `http` in the way you intend. As the error message states, it is not a function but a complete module with a lot of interfaces. Refer to [the documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http) for more information.

Long story short: if you remove the `(app)` after `require('http')`, it probably works.

*update*: I don't think you want to use both expess and http. The functionality you want can be achieved by using just the first ([from MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Server-side/Express_Nodejs/Introduction)):

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const port = 3000;

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.send('Hello World!')
});

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Example app listening on port ${port}!`)
});
```